# When expanding Google Chrome to full screen, a black bar appears at the top

Tags: windows, google-chrome, multiple-monitors, browser

[image: Screenshot]

As soon as Google Chrome expands to full screen, a black bar appears on the top portion of the window. The portion is no longer clickable, as if you were clicking on the desktop, you can even transfer shortcuts on top, it becomes as if transparent.

This happens on 2-monitor setup and the first one remains normal. I found a temporary solution, making the browser itself full screen using F11. But we need to fix it somehow.

Comment: This site is English-only.

Comment: You used Google-translate, but this might not be an efficient way to communicate. In any case, you need to add screenshots to demonstrate the problem.

Comment: "A picture is worth a thousand words" - screenshots showing the symptom will be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found similar reports at Reddit: [MS Edge randomly has large black bar at the top of the screen](https://www.reddit.com/r/techsupport/comments/11f58f0/ms_edge_randomly_has_large_black_bar_at_the_top/).

One reporter SuckinWetNaps also shares [a solution](https://www.reddit.com/r/techsupport/comments/11f58f0/comment/jsrbaiw/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web3x&utm_name=web3xcss&utm_term=1&utm_content=share_button).

> Just had the same issue. I have multiple monitors. I opened display settings, switched from extend, to duplicate, back to extend. And the black bar was gone. I have no idea how it fixed it, but it did.

Note: If this solution works, SuckinWetNaps' Reddit comment should be upvoted.

Comment: At the same moment I use F11 and the problem is solved, and the problem does not arise on the computer or monitor itself, as if the browser begins to conflict.
Several computers in the office suffer from this problem and I would like to somehow find a solution to this, maybe some plugin creates such a conflict.

Comment: F11/full screen is not the same as Maximized @Katsu. While it may be a work-around, the average person does not want the full-screen browser experience.

Comment: If resetting extended screen settings as Shigerello suggests solves the problem, it is likely there is a display driver issue here, or Windows graphical subsystem issue. For an enterprise-wide solution update video drivers, and run the dism /repair commands.